# ¿Se puede pasar un bean por post hacia el servlet?

Tags: java, formularios, servlets

He buscado información al respecto pero nadie dice, se puede o no se puede :(.

Tengo un bean (con metodos getter and setter) y me gustaría enviarlo por parámetro hacia el servlet en un formulario de la siguiente forma:

```
<form action="Servlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="${bean}">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
</form>
```

¿Se puede hacer esto?
En caso de poderse... ¿Cómo lo recibo en el servlet?

Ojalá me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Deberías afinar la pregunta. Si me preguntas "pasar un bean por post", te diré "web services SOAP o REST", pero tu código es de un `form` HTML, que (use POST o GET) tiene un formato muy definido que no tiene nada que ver con web services.

Comment: La respuesta directa es NO, son cosas bien diferentes, lo que debes hacer es enviar tu objeto como un JSON

Comment: @shop350 de hecho hay formas para hacerlo (p.ej. meter la serialización del bean) pero A) son liosas y B) tienen riesgos. Espero que la OP dé más detalles para que se le pueda dar una respuesta sin tener que escribir un libro.

Comment: Siempre hablé de form, java y servlet. Nunca de "web service". Les agradezco tomarse su tiempo para responder. Creo que lo que me recomienda @shop350 es lo mas acertado. Saludos!